# Salesforce REST API: query with date in where clause

Tags: rest-api, query

I am using salesforce REST API to retrieve all the accounts. Something like this:

```
..."/query?q=select+name,+cust_number__c,+cust_status__c+from+account+where+cust_number__c+!=null"
```

I need to retrieve the delta records once a day. So I am planning to use 'lastmodifiedDate'. Retrieve any record where the lastmodifiedDate is greater than my last pull. But I am getting an error

```
.../query?q=select+name,+CreatedDate+,+lastmodifiedDate,+cust_number__c,+cust_status__c+from+account+where+lastmodifiedDate+%3e+2017-04-03T20:12:37.000+0000;
```

> Query was unsuccessful. Status code returned is 400
>   An error has occured. Http status: 400
>
> ```
> [ {
>   "message" : "\nlastmodifiedDate > 2017-04-03T20:12:37.000 0000\n                                         ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:159\nline 1:159 no viable alternative at character ' '",
>   "errorCode" : "MALFORMED_QUERY"
> } ]
> ```

when I try this query:

```
    .../query?q=select+name,+CreatedDate+,+lastmodifiedDate,+cust_number__c,+cust_status__c+from+account+where+lastmodifiedDate+>+2017-04-03T20:12:37.000+0000;
```

> Query URL: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 190:
>
> Exception for '>'

How can I get results with date in the where clause?

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode the plus sign (`+`) in your timezone offset (to `%2B`). Instead of `.000+0000`, use `.000%2B0000`. If you use a plus character (`+`) it will get converted to a space (). Notice your error message clause:

```
lastmodifiedDate > 2017-04-03T20:12:37.000 0000
                                          ^ + character got converted to space
```

Also, if you are terminating your query string with a semicolon (`;`), remove that.

This `WHERE` clause URI should work:

```
WHERE+LastModifiedDate>2017-04-03T20:12:37.000%2B0000
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your response.
I had to encode '>' as well. So the final query that works is

```
.../query?q=select+name,+CreatedDate+,+lastmodifiedDate,+cust_number__c,+cust_status__c+from+account+where+lastmodifiedDate+%3e+2017-04-03T20:12:37.000%2B0000
```

Comment: Interesting, I didn't have to encode `>` in workbench.

Comment: A note on Stack Exchange mechanics: If the above answer [addressed your problem](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. If you have >= 15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.

Comment: I wanted to accept it as the correct answer, but for some very odd reason I do not see a Check mark to the left. Hence I up-voted it!

Comment: You've logged in via separate accounts. You should be able to merge them via the [contact us](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/contact) link.